# hardware questions?

Tags: discussion, gaming-hardware

How should questions related to gaming hardware be handled?

Answer (score 10):

I think we can perfectly complement Super User on this point.

- PC hardware questions should belong on Super User. (unless explicitly about Gaming Accesoires **in combination with** Games)
- Console Hardware questions should be allowed.
- Mixing of console hardware and PC, on a case to case base (allowed: Combining Xbox360 controller with PC to play games.)

Remember:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
>
> and it is not about …
>
> - videogames or consoles
> - [...]
>
> … then Super user in the right place to ask your question!

While:

> Gaming - Stack Exchange is for passionate videogamers from all platforms, including consoles and computers. If your question generally covers …
>
> - PC video gaming
> - Xbox, PS3, Wii gaming
> - Nintendo DS, PSP, iPhone gaming
>
> … then Gaming - Stack Exchange is the right place to ask your question!

Comment: A better separation that what I had thought of.

Comment: We will probably also have a electronic gadgets site for really hardware centered questions. Given that a question about Netflix on your Xbox360 isn't really gaming related

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think we should say no.

My suspicion is that that would be a very PC oriented discussion and would be VERY subjective. I think to maintain a clean and clear flow, just direct all hardware questions elsewhere.

Comment: Would be fine, except.. what is elsewhere?

Comment: @Arda Xi: not here :P Maybe SU?

Comment: But don't they have a strict no-games policy on SU?

Comment: I think if you were asking in relation to "A good video card in this price range" or something along those lines the SU would probably be the place.