# On Meta, [mods] is an alias to [moderators], but there are also discussions about game mods

Tags: discussion, support, tags

I found four questions that use the [moderators](/questions/tagged/moderators) tag while discussing game mods, as in the [mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mods) tag on main. Presumably, these questions used a [mods](/questions/tagged/mods) tag, before it was aliased to [moderators](/questions/tagged/moderators).

- [Do "mod-development" questions belong here?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/562/do-mod-development-questions-belong-here)
- [What's the stance on mods to PC games?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361/whats-the-stance-on-mods-to-pc-games)
- [Are questions about hardware mods on topic?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5492/are-questions-about-hardware-mods-on-topic)
- [Let's talk about [Mods]](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3723/lets-talk-about-mods)

In light of this, should there be a [mods](/questions/tagged/mods) tag to discuss game mods asked about on the main site, on Meta?

Comment: I don't see why not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure, sounds reasonable.

To disambiguate the topic area, I've retagged those questions with [game-modifications](/questions/tagged/game-modifications) and added the synonyms [game-mods](/questions/tagged/game-mods) and [modding](/questions/tagged/modding) too, for good measure. This way the tag is distinct from the "SE mods" [moderators](/questions/tagged/moderators)/[mods](/questions/tagged/mods) tag.

But if you have another suggestion for the top-level tag, let me know and I'll change it.

Comment: I think the [game-mods] tag is important here, so that when someone types in "mods" as a tag, the system will suggest both possible meanings.